# how can we add (long,String) in arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create a list with values of type - (long,String)
like -

```
 ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
         a.add(1L,branchName);
```

How can I do this because if I use list It will accept only int,String.

Comment: can you please explain add(int,String)  as per your understanding?

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that collections can't be typed to primitives - you *must* use the wrapper class instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should note that `ArrayList`'s `add(int,String)` adds the String element in the given int index (if the index is valid). The `int` parameter is not part of the contents of the `ArrayList`.

Perhaps an `ArrayList` is not the correct choice for you. If you wish to map `Long` keys to `String` values, use `Map<Long,String>`.

```
Map<Long,String> a = new HashMap<> ();
a.put(1L,branchName);
```

Comment: I think it´s worth noting that if he wants to have more elements in the list as `Integer.MAX_VALUE`(a guess why he does use long as key) then both structures will fail since both of them can only hold around `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a custom class, e.g.

```
class IndexAndBranchName {
  long index;
  String branchName;
}
```

and then add instances of this to the ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<IndexAndBranchName> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(new IndexAndBranchName(index, branchName));
```

Whether you use this approach or something like Eran's depends upon what you need to use the list for subsequently:

- If you want to look "branches" up by index, use a `Map`; however, you can only store a single value per key; you could use a Guava `Multimap` or similar if you want multiple values per key.
- If you simply want all of the index/branch name pairs, you can use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code for your question.

HashMap is also a better option , but if you want only ArrayList then use it.

```
List<Map<Object, Object>> mylist =  new ArrayList<Map<Object, Object>>();
    Map map =  new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1L, "BranchName");
    mylist.add(map);
```

Comment: That's a really inefficient way of storing a pair of values.